# Where to find All Space Station Frequencies?

Tags: satellites

I am trying to make a list of all ISS downlink/uplink frequencies including ham bands and non-ham bands for a net I just started up, the Amateur Satellite net.

Where can I find all of this? I can only find snippets of stuff everywhere, and I feel like i'm missing some frequencies.

Comment: In space. Remember to bring your spectrum analyzer.

Comment: Keep in mind that the international space station isn't one mission. It's many, many missions with many groups, each with certain knowledge about their equipment and experiments apart from the shared equipment. There may be a coordinator that manages rf info for the iss internally and shares it with all the programs, but they don't maintain that information publicly for a variety of reasons. It's the responsibility of each program to publish the information they own according to their mission requirements. It is likely that you will have to do the research yourself.

Comment: @AdamDavisKD8OAS I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list which I've used a few times from the ISS Fan CLub:

http://www.issfanclub.com/frequencies

This one is has some frequencies from the ISS and associated craft:

http://www.zarya.info/Frequencies/FrequenciesISS.php

On the right hand side of this page, it gives the callsigns which *could* be used:

http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/station/reference/radio/

I would recommend ISStracker for the location, although N2yo and heavens above are also useful for satellite tracking, especially for other types.

Good luck!

**EDIT:** I just came across this a second ago:

**http://www.monitoringtimes.com/html/Monitoring%20NASA%20and%20Space%20Communications.pdf**

It might be a bit out of date (2006) but it might be useful to you. I would also recommend a scanning directory, as they often list stuff like this!